# Could not find coffee-rails-3.2.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep receiving the error message:

> Could not find coffee-rails-3.2.2 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I get this when I am trying to create a database using `rake db:create`.

When I look at the gem list or do a bundle update or install the gem 'coffee-rails-3.2.2' is clearly there.  Why is this happening and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post your full Gemfile and Gemfile.lock please?

Comment: what version of rails?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your gemfile.lock => rm Gemfile.lock
2. Add `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'` to Gemfile
3. Run `bundle install`

Or (without remove Gemfile.lock) you just add `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'` to Gemfile and run `bundle update`